# Xcode 5 on Mountain Lion 10.8.5 won't load

Tags: xcode, macos

Since I installed the Xcode 5 from the App Store I can't start Xcode.

I click on the Xcode icon, then icon bounce 1 time then nothing.

The program doesn't respond...

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Xcode but I got the same problem.

Comment: Wait for sometime, maybe!

Comment: Have you checked Console (found in /Applications/Utilities) for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to completely uninstall XCode and its accompanying utilities.

You can follow [this link](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/) for that.

Comment: I already tried this but I got this error:sudo: /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found

Comment: Same problem: sudo: /Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found

Comment: do you have access to /Library/Developer ? or /Developer/Library ?

Answer (score 0):

I am plagued by this problem. Ever since I updated to XCode 5 I have had nothing but trouble. When I open it it does nothing but it does say Application Not Responding when you right-click the icon in the tray.

Once I walked away and hours later when I came back it was open. So I tried it again and waited. around 30 minutes later, it opened. I've figured out that if you wait long enough, eventually it opens.

I know this is only a temporary, partial solution, but it may be all you have until the release Mavericks. I have read in searching for a solution that XCode 5 works in 10.9 but developers struggle using it on 10.8.5 <----- specifically 5!

I just installed the 10.8.5 supplemental 1.0 update and it didn't change anything for me.

Try to open the program and see if letting it sit for a while maybe even overnight, and see if it opens like mine. If so, maybe someone can help with that extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have the exact same problem that you are facing. This is how you can solve it:

First of all just uninstall the current version of Xcode from your Mac completely. You can delete it from the Applications. After that you will still see the Xcode icon in the LaunchPad and i don't know why. You have to delete it from the LaunchPad too. Just by clicking and holding until the cross button appears and then press the cross button to delete.

Once this is done, don't download it from the App Store. Instead download from a direct link. Go to this [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and find the Xcode and download the DMG file. Then you can install it and you will have no problem.

You can either waste your time troubleshooting the problem or you can just do what i told you to save some time. The choice is yours!

Hope this helps!